# Why is my vector initialisation making all objects in my array the same?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, c++17

I'm working on a program to aid me in world-building that randomly generates a settlement (hamlet, village, town, city) based on a nation (German, Latin, Eastern) that the user chooses. I've integrated a sort of settler generation system to create settlers within the settlement, each with a name, age, gender, and wealth using a constructor and holding the results as objects within a vector. Unfortunately, the program creates an entire population of clones, filling the vector with settlers with the same name, age, etc.

I've tried initialising the Settler class' constructor in a for loop, but that hasn't changed anything except causing you to get a different set of settlers each time you request information on one of them.

### Settler Constructor:

```cpp
class Settler {
  public:
  int settlerAge;
  string settlerName;
  string settlerGender;
  string settlerWealth;

  Settler(int type, int nation, int quantity) {
    int result{};
    string givenName{};
    string surName{};
    // Latin Male First Name
    string latinMaleName[15] = {"Faustus", "Mamercus", "Mettius", "Appius", "Hostus", "Quintus", "Cossus", "Secundus", "Servius", "Gallio", "Tettienus", "Petronius", "Paesentius", "Pescunnius", "Clodius"};
    // Latin Surname
    string latinSurname[30] = {"Natalinus", "Lucilianus", "Crispian", "Laetinianus", "Falco", "Otho", "Plautius", "Pascentius", "Lepidus", "Moderatus", "Caeparius", "Caetronius", "Hostilius", "Aedinius", "Papius", "Gennadia", "Triaria", "Planta","Amantia", "Mico", "Opilio", "Augusta", "Laevina", "Longina", "Mico", "Servana", "Sicula", "Iovina", "Albana", "Concessa"};
    // Latin Female First Name
    string latinFemaleName[15] = {"Vorenia", "Tuccia", "Consentia", "Vinicia", "Aurelia", "Helvia", "Fabia", "Aemilia", "Petilia", "Cloelia", "Viducia", "Betiliena", "Sornatia", "Memmia", "Pedia"};
    // As above, so below...
    string germanMaleName[15] = {"Carsten", "Benedikt", "Emmerich", "Tillmann", "Maik", "Severin", "Adrian", "Gregor", "Ingolf", "Germund", "Adelmar", "Eckard", "Raimund", "Marwin", "Dietmar"};
    string germanSurname[30] = {"Loeb", "Spielberg", "Lindemann", "Frenz", "Buxbaum", "Macher", "Bacharach", "Homrighausen", "Faulhaber", "Herder", "Germar", "Eisen", "Hackl", "Specht", "Rossmann", "Erdmann", "Osterhaus", "Steinsaltz", "Spiegelmann", "Lindemann", "Kluckhohn", "Kuttner", "Seelmann", "Sattler", "Kautner", "Dunhaupt", "Scharf", "Preisner", "Werthner", "Breitner"};
    string germanFemaleName[15] = {"Selina", "Isabel", "Walburg", "Berta", "Kate", "Gisela", "Amelie", "Ronja", "Karin", "Lena", "Alexandra", "Sarah", "Monica", "Kai", "Nadja"};
    // NOTE: Surname is before given name in eastern nations
    string easternMaleName[15] = {"Nikki", "Moronobu", "Yaichiro", "Shuncho", "Tamasaburo", "Sekien", "Kazutoshi", "Yasuhide", "Omezo", "Kinzo", "Junji", "Utamuro", "Hisaki", "Taki", "Mitsuo"};
    string easternSurname[30] = {"Maki", "Shinohara", "Tsukino", "Ikeda", "Matsutoya", "Sakata", "Horiuchi", "Suda", "Tsuga", "Kawano", "Kanbayashi", "Kirigaya", "Sakimoto", "Urushido", "Inaba", "Tsukiyomi", "Saeki", "Soga", "Morioka", "Yamabe", "Nakajima", "Maruyama", "Suga", "Kamino", "Kawamoto", "Takanashi", "Ito", "Kuramoto", "Maeda", "Kanemaru"};
    string easternFemaleName[15] = {"Saito", "Ane", "Fuuko", "Taji", "Isoko", "Gen", "Kuwa", "Taira", "Sachi", "Uka", "Ryoko", "Hina", "Mitsu", "Asa", "Tomie"};

    // Gender Generation (Male/Female)
    result = (1 + (rand() % 2));
    if (result > 1) {
      settlerGender = "female";
    } else {
      settlerGender = "male";
    }

    // Name and Age Generation (See Arrays)
    result = (rand() % 15);
    switch(nation) {
      case 1: // Latin (Equal split of ages)
      if (settlerGender == "male") {
        givenName = latinMaleName[result];
      } else {
        givenName = latinFemaleName[result];
      }
      result = (1 + (rand() % 100));
      if (result >= 66) {
        settlerAge = (41 + (rand() % 30));
      } else if (result > 33 || result < 66) {
        settlerAge = (22 + (rand() % 41));
      } else {
        settlerAge = (1 + (rand() % 22));
      }
      result = (rand() % 30);
      surName = latinSurname[result];
      settlerName = givenName + " " + surName;
      break;
      case 2: // German (More young people)
      if (settlerGender == "male") {
        givenName = germanMaleName[result];
      } else {
        givenName = germanFemaleName[result];
      }
      result = (1 + (rand() % 100));
      if (result >= 90) {
        settlerAge = (41 + (rand() % 30));
      } else if (result > 40 || result < 90) {
        settlerAge = (22 + (rand() % 41));
      } else {
        settlerAge = (1 + (rand() % 22));
      }
      result = (rand() % 30);
      surName = germanSurname[result];
      settlerName = givenName + " " + surName;
      break;
      case 3: // Eastern (More older people)
      if (settlerGender == "male") {
        givenName = easternMaleName[result];
      } else {
        givenName = easternFemaleName[result];
      }
      result = (1 + (rand() % 100));
      if (result >= 40) {
        settlerAge = (41 + (rand() % 30));
      } else if (result > 20 || result < 40) {
        settlerAge = (22 + (rand() % 41));
      } else {
        settlerAge = (1 + (rand() % 22));
      }
      result = (rand() % 30);
      surName = easternSurname[result];
      settlerName = surName + " " + givenName;
      break;
    }

    // Wealth Generation (Poor/Decent/Rich: Based on Surname)
    switch(type){
      case 1: // Hamlet
      if (result >= 28) {
        settlerWealth = "Rich";
      } else if (result > 24 || result < 28) {
        settlerWealth = "Decent";
      } else {
        settlerWealth = "Poor";
      }
      break;
      case 2: // Village
      if (result >= 26) {
        settlerWealth = "Rich";
      } else if (result > 19 || result < 26) {
        settlerWealth = "Decent";
      } else {
        settlerWealth = "Poor";
      }
      break;
      case 3: // Town
      if (result >= 25) {
        settlerWealth = "Rich";
      } else if (result > 9 || result < 25) {
        settlerWealth = "Decent";
      } else {
        settlerWealth = "Poor";
      }
      break;
      case 4: // City
      if (result >= 20) {
        settlerWealth = "Rich";
      } else if (result > 9 || result < 20) {
        settlerWealth = "Decent";
      } else {
        settlerWealth = "Poor";
      }
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

### Vector Initialisation and Output:

```cpp
    Settlement objSettlement(tempType,tempNation);
    int tempNum = objSettlement.settlementQuantity;
    std::vector<Settler> objSettler(objSettlement.settlementQuantity, Settler(tempType, tempNation, tempNum));
    cout << "Welcome to the " << objSettlement.settlementType << " " << objSettlement.settlementName << " in the " << objSettlement.settlementNation << " nation!\n";
    cout << "Featuring a population of " << objSettlement.settlementQuantity << " with " << objSettlement.settlementWealth << " wealth.\n\n";

    bool repeat = true;
    while (repeat == true) {
      cout << "Enter the ID of a settler you would like to read about (from 0-" << (objSettlement.settlementQuantity - 1) << ", or enter 999999 to exit): ";
      cin >> tempNum;
      cout << "\n\n";
      if (tempNum == 999999) {
        repeat = false;
      } else {
      cout << objSettler[tempNum].settlerName << ", " << objSettler[tempNum].settlerGender << ", is " << objSettler[tempNum].settlerAge << " years old and has " << objSettler[tempNum].settlerWealth << " wealth.\n\n";
      }
    }
```

For context, "objSettlement" refers to a randomly generated Settlement instance and ".settlementQuantity" is an integer representing the settlement's population.

So, when I create a latin hamlet with 30 people, the program creates a vector with 30 cases of: "Faustus Crispian, male, is 41 years old and has Poor wealth." regardless of what number I put in from 0-29.

Why is my vector initialisation making all objects in my array the same?

Comment: Maybe provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example would be easier (and mostly faster) to understand your problem.

Comment: Your program has a lot of things not related to your problem. Strip off everything that is not necessary to show your problem. Just make an [mcve]. TIP: it would be easier to read your program is you limit it at 80 columns

Comment: 1) Use a debugger to debug your code.  2) Break up your constructor into several functions.  The tell-tale sign it is too big is you putting in comments like this: `// Name and Age Generation (See Arrays)` followed by a mountain of code.  Comments are not functions -- create a function, give it a meaningful name such as `GenerateNameAndAge` or something like that, and call it.

Comment: Dimfred & Amadeus: that guide is not helpful or beginner friendly, my issue is that I can't identify what is actually causing the problem, so I can't cut it down to exactly what is relevant without fixing the issue myself.
PaulMcKenzie: I don't know how to competently debug the code with the limited tools I have, but the note about turning those sections into functions is helpful for future optimisation.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn You can start cutting pieces of code and see if the result shows the error. Do that until you have a small program that still shows the problem

Comment: @Amadeus while I understand making a reprex can sometimes make a problem more identifiable or at least easier for other people to read, it requires you to know what you're doing when you're minimising the code so it still reproduces the problem. If the code is too long for you to read, I can't help you with that, because I'm still learning the language and I'm not comfortable enough with it to cut chunks out while knowing the relevant stuff is there. As we saw in another answer, I actually didn't include enough and they recommended something I've already done.

Comment: But that's how you learn to debug it. Putting that off doesn't help you, and it won't produce quality questions. It's not optional, I'm afraid. You can easily see whether "the relevant stuff is there" because it'll still exhibit the problem you're asking about; if it doesn't, it isn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and when I'm ready to try debugging I will. But it's genuinely something I can't do using online IDEs and Compilers right now without access to a proper IDE like Visual Studio or Code::Blocks that feature actual comprehensible debugging tools. It isn't something that was required because as you can see below, someone took the time to read the code and was kind enough to provide an answer. You can criticise me for being lazy by not debugging, but you're also essentially asking for a code-TLDR.

Comment: Now imagine that we get thousands of these every day, which we do. Doing debugging first is not so much to ask before you request free help. You probably would have found the problem yourself if you'd done so, _and_ learnt a valuable skill. No need to get snippy about it! The How To Ask section is quite clear about what we expect for debugging questions here. Cheers.

Comment: @SamsyTheUnicorn so. let me understand, are you coding a kind of complex program but are you unable to strip off some part of it, to make it easy for us to help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This :

```
std::vector<Settler> objSettler(objSettlement.settlementQuantity, Settler(tempType, tempNation, tempNum));
```

creates a vector with `objSettlement.settlementQuantity` copies of the same object `Settler(tempType, tempNation, tempNum)`.

Refer to this [reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for details on how the various vector constructors work.

Something like this might be closer to what you want :

```
std::vector<Settler> objSettler;
for (int i = 0; i < objSettlement.settlementQuantity; ++i) {
    objSettler.emplace_back(tempType, tempNation, tempNum);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create your `objSettler` vector, you create one Settler randomly, which will get copied `objSettlement.settlementQuantity` times. In other words, your constructor is called only once and the instances in the vector are created from that one settler object using the default copy constructor.

See [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

For generating n random settlers, you might want to use [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) and [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
std::vector<Settler> objSettler;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(objSettler),
                objSettlement.settlementQuantity,
                [&](){ return Settler(tempType, tempNation, tempNum); });
```